# Microsoft Access Deleting Entries

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on an MS Access database that's housed on a shared drive.

I've been experiencing issues where I'll update/add new entries and come back later to find that the changes are no longer there.

I was told by my IT department that it's due to the fact that the shared drive was *"not created to run apps like Access."*

I know I can split the database and have everyone have a local copy on their desktop, but it seems like it will be limiting and tedious.

What are my other options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you altering the database with access forms?  If so, I would split the database into forms and data.  On the client side (each user's desktop) would have the forms piece with a 'linked' table/query to the shared data database on the shared drive.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

Are you altering the database with access forms? If so, I would split the database into forms and data. On the client side (each user's desktop) would have the forms piece with a 'linked' table/query to the shared data database on the shared drive. HTH

Here is a URL how-to reference:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-an-access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc

Answer (score 0):

Whether split or unsplit; if you make changes to data they do not disappear.  If its edits of existing data you must have some sort of version control issue going on which I don't understand.  If it is new entries - then typically the issue is that it is not getting the necessary foreign key into the record, so that next time you look at it - it doesn't show as it is essentially an orphan record not linked to its parent.  This is due to a design flaw or possibly you are circumventing the intended entry form.

There is no such thing as a server not designed to run Access - presuming that it has a Windows OS ….

All multi user Access applications are to be a split deployment.